# For command token doesn't work when there are empty fields in the record

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, token

I am trying to extract the values from the third field of a file which has data records.

The fields are separated by vertical bar characters:

```
9001||10454145||60|60
9001|234467|10454145||60|60
9001|234457|10454145||60|60
```

Command is -

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=|" %%A IN ('Findstr /i "9001" .\itemloc\%%~nf.dat') do (
 echo  %%A >> log.txt
)
```

But the output I am getting is

```
60
10454145
10454145
```

The empty fields are messing up my output. Any suggestions how to make the `for` `token` work with empty fields in the record?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q75199035.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=|" %%y IN ("!line:||=|(missing)|!") DO ECHO %%y
)
)>"%outfile%"

TYPE "%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

The magic is that for each line, `||` is replaced by `|(missing)|`.

This simple solution has its faults - for instance if there is `|||` in the source data, or the usual suspects (some punctuation symbols like `!`) but should be quite happy with alphameric source text.

Another way would be to use a third-party utility like `sed` to pre-process the source data.

The fundamental reason for this phenomenon is that `for/f` parses the line as `[delimiters]token1[delimiters]token2...`, where `[delimiters]` is any sequence of any of the delimiter characters.